# LibreOffice Calc Basic search and replace macro

Tags: macros, find-and-replace, libreoffice-calc

I am attempting to create a LibreOffice Basic macro for use in Calc that when invoked in an open spreadsheet file will open a second spreadsheet file that contains two ranges, (the first range containing cells with regular expressions to search for and the second containing the replacement text) then will search in the sheet it was invoked from for all the items in the search range and replace any items found in the working sheet with the corresponding replacement cell including cell the formatting of the replacement cell.
I asked ChatGPT for help and the following is in general what it supplied, with some corrections that I made to the logic that determines the size of the range.

---

```
Sub SearchAndReplaceItems

    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim oSearchReplaceDoc As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object
    Dim oSearchReplaceSheet As Object
    Dim oSearchDescriptor As Object
    Dim oSearchRange As Object
    Dim oReplaceDescriptor As Object
    Dim oCell As Object
    Dim oFound As Object
    Dim nSearchColumn As Integer
    Dim nReplaceColumn As Integer
    Dim nLastRow As Integer

    ' Get the current document
    oDoc = ThisComponent

    ' Specify the path to the Corrections spreadsheet
    Dim sSearchReplaceFilePath As String
    sSearchReplaceFilePath = "C:\Users\One\Info\Corrections.ods"

    ' Open the Corrections spreadsheet
    oSearchReplaceDoc = StarDesktop.loadComponentFromURL(ConvertToURL(sSearchReplaceFilePath), "_blank", 0, Array())
    oSearchReplaceSheet = oSearchReplaceDoc.Sheets(0)

    ' Specify the column numbers for search and replace text
    nSearchColumn = 1 ' Assuming search text is in column A
    nReplaceColumn = 2 ' Assuming replace text is in column B

    ' Get the range for the search regular expressions
    oSearchRange = oSearchReplaceDoc.Sheets(0).getCellRangeByName("SearchRegExps")

    ' Get the last row with data in the SearchRegExps range
    nLastRow = oSearchRange.Rows.getCount()

    ' Loop through each row History Item Corrections sheet
    For i = 1 To nLastRow
        ' Get search and replace values from the current row
        Dim sSearchText As String
        Dim sReplaceText As String
        sSearchText = oSearchReplaceSheet.getCellByPosition(nSearchColumn - 1, i).getString()
        sReplaceText = oSearchReplaceSheet.getCellByPosition(nReplaceColumn - 1, i).getString()

        ' Create search and replace descriptors
        oSearchDescriptor = oDoc.createSearchDescriptor()
        oSearchDescriptor.SearchString = sSearchText

        oReplaceDescriptor = oDoc.createReplaceDescriptor()
        oReplaceDescriptor.ReplaceString = sReplaceText

        ' Execute the search
        oFound = oDoc.createReplaceDescriptor()
        oFound = oDoc.findFirst(oSearchDescriptor)

        ' Replace each occurrence found
        Do While Not IsNull(oFound)
            oCell = oFound.Cell
            oCell.setString(sReplaceText)

            ' Copy formatting from replace cell to the found cell
            CopyCellFormatting(oCell, oFound.Cell)

            ' Find the next occurrence
            oFound = oDoc.findNext(oFound)
        Loop
    Next i

    ' Close the search and replace document
    oSearchReplaceDoc.Close(True)
End Sub

Sub CopyCellFormatting(oSourceCell, oTargetCell)
    ' Copy character formatting
    oTargetCell.CharFontName = oSourceCell.CharFontName
    oTargetCell.CharHeight = oSourceCell.CharHeight
    oTargetCell.CharWeight = oSourceCell.CharWeight
    oFound.Cell.CharAutoKerning = oCell.CharAutoKerning
    oFound.Cell.CharKerning = oCell.CharKerning
    oFound.Cell.CharScaleWidth = oCell.CharScaleWidth

    ' Copy border formatting
    oTargetCell.BottomBorder = oSourceCell.BottomBorder
    oTargetCell.TopBorder = oSourceCell.TopBorder
    oTargetCell.LeftBorder = oSourceCell.LeftBorder
    oTargetCell.RightBorder = oSourceCell.RightBorder

End Sub
```

---

When I run the macro the error

> BASIC runtime error.
> Property or method not found: createSearchDescriptor.

occurs on line 50 of the macro, which is:

> oSearchDescriptor = oDoc.createSearchDescriptor()

I comprehend that the object oDoc (the document that the macro was invoked from) does not have a property or method named createSearchDescriptor, but I don't know enough LibreOffice Basic to figure what it should be doing here so that it will work. I looked through Andrew Pitonyak's book "Useful Macro Information For OpenOffice.org" and his "OpenOffice.org Macros Explained" book but did not find anything in them about using SearchDescriptors.

I suspect that a similar error would occur if the statement on line 53

> oReplaceDescriptor = oDoc.createReplaceDescriptor()

were to be executed.

It would not surprise me if there were other errors in this code that will prevent it from running successfully.

I would greatly appreciate any insight that can be provided into how I can achieve what I desire to accomplish with this macro.

Comment: Yes, you are right - the spreadsheet does not have a `.createSearchDescriptor()` method, every sheet of the spreadsheet has this method. By the way, how many sheets are in your modifiable workbook? Should the replacement be carried out on each of these sheets or only on the first? *(Seeking help from the AI was not the best way to solve the problem)*

Comment: Voted to close this question because [use of ChatGPT is banned on Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14862/use-of-chatgpt-is-now-banned-on-super-user).

Comment: [Microsoft invested $10 billion in ChatGPT](https://www.forbes.com/sites/qai/2023/01/27/microsoft-confirms-its-10-billion-investment-into-chatgpt-changing-how-microsoft-competes-with-google-apple-and-other-tech-giants/?sh=592152053624). Do you really expect that after this the AI will give reasonable advice on how to use the **free** office?

Comment: @JimK I think you misunderstand the ban. ChatGPT is perfectly valid for "doing your homework", though it is probably a poor choice unless you have some knowledge already to check its info against. The ban is against using that tool to generate questions or answers. OP used it to try to solve their own problem first.

Comment: @JohnSUN it does not follow. MS supports tons of open source and free products, and ChatGPT gives silly code answers to tons of MS product questions too.

Comment: @music2myear: The linked page from SO says, "*All* (emphasis theirs) use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow." It sounds like you're saying "all" doesn't mean what I think it does! In this case, the poster used ChatGPT to hallucinate code, then posted the code and asked why it didn't work. Seems like a waste of our effort, and potentially misleading for anyone who reads or searches this, the kind of thing the policy was intended to prevent. However, the code and related parts could be removed and then the question would be fine.

Comment: By the way, I regularly use ChatGPT to assist in coding, so I'm not generally against it, only against using it to generate large amounts of useless or misleading content and then posting it.

Comment: @JohnSUN. If I understand your comment of two days ago you are saying that the .createSearchDescriptor() and .createSearchDescriptor() methods should be preceded by an oSheet rather than an oDoc?

Comment: @JohnSUN, In answer to the question about where the replacements should be carried out, they should be carried out only within the active sheet where the macro is invoked.
However, after studying your response I came to the conclusion that the spreadsheet containing the macro should also contain the sheet of search regular expressions and replacement cells and the sheet where the replacements occur. Once the replacements have been made the contents of that sheet can be moved to the their final destination in another spreadsheet file.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to stir up controversy or violate any Super User bans. I am just an old school programmer who learned the art before the advent of Object Oriented Programming who is trying to understand the objects, properties and methods that are used by LO Basic so that I can write a macro that will perform a rather repetitive task. As such I am having a difficult time finding information on what those objects are, what the properties and methods associated with them are and what they do.

Comment: @JimK, Close the question if you must. At this point I don't see a way to exorcise the offending parts from both my original question and the comments.

Comment: *"I am having a difficult time finding information on what those objects are, what the properties and methods associated with them are and what they do."* — This can be discovered with the [MRI extension](https://github.com/hanya/MRI/releases), along with the [API documentation](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/index.html) and other references such as the Ask LibreOffice forum. ChatGPT is not helpful for this purpose, at least not currently. *"I did not mean to stir up controversy."* — No worries, I'm just trying to understand how to implement the new policy.

Comment: @JimK, Thanks for the references to where I can find information.
After thinking about the "_new policy_" for a bit yesterday I think that it seems that it is a bit naive to believe that it will actually prevent posters from posting ChatGPT generated code, It seems to me that all it will prevent is people admitting that they are posting it. What is to stop someone from saying **I have this code that is not working** and posting it without admitting/specifying where it came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will tell you how this problem is solved step by step.

The main problem is copying the replacement cell along with the formatting. There are several ways to perform this operation - through the clipboard (the usual copy and paste - chapter ***5.23.1. Copy Spreadsheet Cells With The Clipboard***), using `.getTransferable()` (chapter ***5.23.6. An alternative to the clipboard – transferable content***). But the most effective method is `oSheet.CopyRange()` (chapter ***5.23.2. Copy Spreadsheet Cells Without The Clipboard***)

Unfortunately, this method is only useful within a single spreadsheet, and your data and the substitution list are in different spreadsheets. Therefore, we will use a not very complicated trick - we will create a temporary sheet in the current workbook with a copy of the list of replacements, and after finishing the work we will delete it.

It is customary to place all Dim operators at the beginning of the procedure. I will describe each variable immediately before using it.

In order not to search for text strings throughout the macro code in case you need to change them, we place them at the very beginning of the procedure:

```
Sub SearchAndReplaceItems
Const sSearchReplaceFilePath = "C:\Users\One\Info\Corrections.ods"
Const sSearchReplaceRangeName = "SearchRegExps"
```

As always, preliminary data checking and configuration takes up most of the code.

The [**Tools library**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/03/lib_tools.html?DbPAR=BASIC) contains many useful functions. We will use `GetDocumentType()` function and `OpenDocument()` function

```
    GlobalScope.BasicLibraries.LoadLibrary("Tools")
' Get the current document
Dim oDoc As Variant 
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    If GetDocumentType(oDoc) <> "scalc" Then
        MsgBox "This macro is intended for use with spreadsheets only!", MB_ICONSTOP, "Continuation of work is impossible"
        Exit Sub
    EndIf
```

If the replacement dictionary does not exist, then everything else is meaningless

```
    If Not FileExists(sSearchReplaceFilePath) Then
        MsgBox "File '" & sSearchReplaceFilePath & "' not found!", MB_ICONSTOP, "Continuation of work is impossible"
        Exit Sub
    EndIf 
Dim oSearchReplaceDoc As Variant 
    oSearchReplaceDoc = OpenDocument(ConvertToURL(sSearchReplaceFilePath), Array())
```

Let's make sure the spreadsheet of substitutions is not corrupted

```
Dim oNamedRanges As Variant
    oNamedRanges = oSearchReplaceDoc.NamedRanges
    If Not oNamedRanges.hasByName(sSearchReplaceRangeName) Then
        MsgBox "The '" & sSearchReplaceFilePath & "' file does not contain a named range '" _
            & sSearchReplaceRangeName & "'!", MB_ICONSTOP, "Continuation of work is impossible"
```

At this point we could close the reference spreadsheet
`oSearchReplaceDoc.close(true)`.
But since you most likely want to correct the detected error, we will not do this

```
        Exit Sub
    EndIf
```

Let's collect the necessary information about the range of replacements:
the name of the sheet and the location of the named range on this sheet

```
Dim NamedRange As Variant
Dim oReferredCells As Variant
Dim aRangeAddress As New com.sun.star.table.CellRangeAddress
Dim nStartColumn As Long
Dim nStartRow As Long
Dim nEndRow As Long
Dim sSheetName As String
    NamedRange = oSearchReplaceDoc.NamedRanges.getByName(sSearchReplaceRangeName)

    oReferredCells = NamedRange.getReferredCells()
    aRangeAddress = oReferredCells.getRangeAddress()
    nStartColumn = aRangeAddress.StartColumn
    nStartRow = aRangeAddress.StartRow
    nEndRow = aRangeAddress.EndRow
    sSheetName = oReferredCells.getSpreadsheet().getName()
```

Now we can actually close the substitution spreadsheet - we will get access to its data in another way.

```
    oSearchReplaceDoc.close(true)
```

All further work is carried out only with the current spreadsheet `oDoc`

To ensure that the name of the auxiliary additional sheet does not coincide with an already existing sheet, we will come up with an “almost random” name for it:

```
Dim sTempSheetName As String
    sTempSheetName = sSearchReplaceRangeName & Format(Timer,"0")
```

Let's make sure that there is no such sheet in the current spreadsheet (and if there is, then delete it) and create a new sheet at the end of the spreadsheet. Using the [**link()**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XSheetLinkable.html#link) method, copy the data from the list of replacements into it:

```
Dim oSheets As Variant
Dim nCount As Long
Dim oTempSheet As Variant
    oSheets = ThisComponent.getSheets()
    If oSheets.hasByName(sTempSheetName) Then oSheets.removeByName(sTempSheetName)
    nCount = oSheets.getCount()
    oSheets.insertNewByName(sTempSheetName, nCount)
    oTempSheet = oSheets.getByIndex(nCount)
    oTempSheet.link(ConvertToURL(sSearchReplaceFilePath), sSheetName, "calc8", "", com.sun.star.sheet.SheetLinkMode.VALUE)
```

Now that all the preliminary checks and settings have been made, the actual search and replace is very simple.

```
Dim nCountReplacements As Long 
Dim nNextSheet As Long 
Dim oNextSheet As Variant
Dim nReplRow As Long 
Dim oSearchDescriptor As Variant
Dim sSearchStr As String 
Dim oFormattedCellAddress As Variant
Dim oFound As Variant
Dim oCell As Variant
```

For each sheet in the spreadsheet (except the last one - the last sheet is the list of replacements) create a search descriptor, set its parameters `SearchRegularExpression` and `SearchType` (**1** means [**"search in values"**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Text/Navigating#Search_and_Replace))

```
    For nNextSheet = 0 To nCount-1
        oNextSheet = oSheets.getByIndex(nNextSheet)
        oSearchDescriptor = oNextSheet.createSearchDescriptor()
        oSearchDescriptor.SearchRegularExpression = True
        oSearchDescriptor.SearchType = 1
```

For each line in the replacement list, get the search string and **the address of the replacement cell** (see chapter ***5.23.2. Copy Spreadsheet Cells Without The Clipboard***)

```
        For nReplRow = nStartRow To nEndRow
            sSearchStr = oTempSheet.getCellByPosition(nStartColumn, nReplRow).getString()
            oFormattedCellAddress = oTempSheet.getCellByPosition(nStartColumn+1, nReplRow).getRangeAddress()
            oSearchDescriptor.setSearchString(sSearchStr)
            oFound = oNextSheet.findAll(oSearchDescriptor)
```

If the search for the next regular expression was successful, iterate through all the found cells and copy the sample cell into them. At the same time, we count the number of replacements performed for the report.

```
            If Not IsNull(oFound)  Then 
                For Each oCell In oFound.getCells()
                    oTempSheet.copyRange(oCell.getCellAddress(), oFormattedCellAddress)
                    nCountReplacements = nCountReplacements + 1
```

This is all. Close all checks and cycles, remove the auxiliary sheet, report completion of work:

```
                Next oCell
            EndIf 
        Next nReplRow
    Next nNextSheet
    If oSheets.hasByName(sTempSheetName) Then oSheets.removeByName(sTempSheetName)
    MsgBox nCountReplacements & " substitutions made", MB_ICONINFORMATION, "Done"
End Sub
```

*Hope this was helpful*

Comment: Thank you very much, JohnSun, I will study your answer and try it out at the first opportunity that I get.